# Browser crash with Flash video in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, adobe-flash

Firefox crashes every time I open a web page with video. This looks like a Flash problem: what can be wrong? I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 1):

I have had three 10.04.4 machines crash since ubuntu update the first week of june. They lose bookmarks and will not play video or audio. Im pretty sure it has to do with firefox. I have been using 10.4 for years and prefer it. When I could not find a fix I reinstalled 10.4 and used it fine before allowing updates. When update 237 items it crashes and does the same thing. The bug is in the ubuntu updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to see if it will also work for you. It is likely the plugin, assuming that your install is standard:

1. shut down firefox
2. > sudo aptitude reinstall flashplugin-nonfree
3. start firefox

If you don't have `aptitude`, you can use `sudo apt-get install aptitude` first.

You can also try to purge the package then reinstall it.